# How is a website determining my location even via VPN?

Tags: web-browser, vpn, geolocation

I'm currently in China, and accessing the Internet via a VPN in the USA. When I access Google maps or other location-based web services, they all show my location as that of the VPN server. However, when I accessed a web site - http://www.ikea.com - the site redirected me to the local China site.

I've installed `NoScript`, `Ghostery`, set `enable.geolocation=false`, cleared all history and cookies, and verified that all traffic is sent via the VPN gateway, but despite all this, I'm *always* routed to the local site.

**How** is this being done??

Comment: What language is your browser in? Some websites check the browser language to send you to the appropriate website, maybe Ikea uses this method too.

Comment: My browser (Firefox) shows 2 languages: en-US and en.

Comment: Try installing FireBug and inspecting the traffic between you and e.g. ikea.com . Even better if you can sniff the traffic from the browser to *anywhere* (e.g. the Google servers). I don't believe in magic, so there must be *something* that is either spontaneously sent, or queried of your browser, and that something has to travel through your connection.

Comment: @Adnan Since Google Maps is showing the VPN endpoint, it's a different mechanism at play.

Answer (score 7):

Something isn't adding up here. I've tried so many combinations and I wasn't able to reproduce your situation. This leads me to believe that your VPN provider is leaking your original IP address.

**1.** I opened `ikea.com` using a clean browser (fresh portable Firefox). It took me to to the default locale selection page.

[image]

**2.** Using another clean browser, I opened `ikea.com` using a Chinese proxy, I was redirected to `ikea.com/cn/en`

[image]

**3.** Using the same browser from step #2 (to ensure that any detection cookies or configurations are preserved) I went to `ikea.com` using my normal connection. I was taken to the default locale selection page.

**4.** Again, I used another Chinese proxy and I was redirected to `ikea.com/cn/en`.

**5.** Finally, I tried a U.S. proxy, and I was taken to the same locale selection page.

You're either falsifying or withholding some information, or your VPN provider is somehow revealing your IP.

In all cases I used the same [browser language configurations you're using](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36845/how-is-a-website-determining-my-location-even-via-vpn#comment57767_36847)

> My browser (Firefox) shows 2 languages: en-US and en.

[image]

**Update:**

I've just performed another test. Using my normal connection, I've disabled JavaScript to make sure that there's no JavaScript hocus pocus going on. Then I modified the HTTP `Accept-Language` header to `zh-CN,zh`. I was still taken to the locale selection page.

It's safe to assume that IKEA website is pretty dumb and it's only using the IP address to determine the locale.